Equation X is given "by" or "as"?
Which sentence is correct?

Equation A is given by x+y=z.
Equation A is given as x+y=z.


Why do you need something more than "Equation A is...". You might say "property A is given/calculated by..."

This is a specialist maths usage, and is better asked on Mathematics.SE.

@Edwin: It's actually not a specialist maths usage. Would you say "The price is given as $35"? Probably not. And for similar reasons, you shouldn't say "Equation A is given as x+y=z." In this case, maths usage isn't any different than ordinary English usage.

@Peter Shor  I certainly wouldn't say 'Equation A is given by x + y = z'. //   'x + y = z [which we will call equation A].', maybe. //  The typical maths usage is 'The velocity of a particle is given by the equation v= 4t+cos4t where t is the [numerical value of the] time in seconds and v is the [numerical value of the] velocity in ms⁻¹'. As Stuart implies.

Both options are unnecessarily bloated/pompous. 1. Equation A (simply) is x+y=z. 2. This equation can be written (or even given) as  x+y-z=0. 3. On the other hand, the vertical height y is given by x+y=z. (This third example parallels @EdwinAshworth's comment; here, "A is given by B" means "A can be determined/found using B" and does not mean "A is B".)

@ryang Physics (as taught in the UK at least) unnecessarily complicates this (or used to), but in maths we distinguished measurements and pure number (so  'the vertical height y' would be avoided): 'y is the numerical value of the height, working in metres'.

@EdwinAshworth You're exactly correct that I was labelling y loosely; labelling it at all was merely to draw attention to the fact that in Usage 3, A is a value/expression while B is an equation (that is, we are not claiming A and B to be the same object).

IMHO, neither is correct. In mathematics one would say Let equation A be x+y=z

Because we are assigning values to labels (A being the label and "X being the value),  "As" would be more correct - in this context it's synonymous to "Equals".
A more common/casual/shorter way of saying it is generally "Equation A is x+y=z."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In this instance, the intended meaning of 'given' appears to be one of rendition, rather than of engaged action. The narrative voice is conveying information but is not the active creator of that information. Therefore it should be 'given as' (rendered as) and not 'given by' (created by).
